# Would have in if clause

Tags: grammaticality

What does it mean when " would have " is used in if clause, according to the general form of the third conditional sentence - had + past participle is used with if clause .
But in this sentence -
" If I would have known it, I would have stayed at home.
What's the implication in such sentences

Comment: Some people use _would have_ instead of just past perfect _had_ in _if_ clauses. It's a variation and there's no difference in meaning.

Comment: In other words, I did not know it, so I did not stay home. If things were different, I would have acted differently.

Comment: @JohnLawler In a nitpicky mood I would have said that "If I would have..." was incorrect, but I cannot deny that it is widely used.

Comment: I agree with @DJClayworth; it's understandable but incorrect.

Comment: Given that your standard of "correctness" is not actual use by native speakers, what ***is*** your standard of what's correct in English? And why do you support it?

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm afraid I agree with Messrs Clayworth and Hat: *If I would have known it,* has an implied time clause *at that time* and this cannot sit with the present perfect. The simple past works.

Comment: *If I would have known it* is entirely grammatical. Some people might not like it, but that's style and personal choice. To me, it sounds natural, even if not the most common construction.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> Some people use *would have* instead of just past perfect *had* in *if* clauses. It's a variation and there's no difference in meaning.