# If I would have known

Tags: grammaticality

Is the title of one of Kyle Hume's songs "If I would have known" grammatical?
If so, what's the difference between If I had known and If I would have known?

Comment: [Some people use would have instead of just past perfect had in if clauses. It's a variation and there's no difference in meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/540110/would-have-in-if-clause#comment1323366_540110) Mind you, *some* people (including me) are quite happy with *If I **had have** known...* if we're forced to avoid the contraction in *If **I'd have known** you were coming I'd have baked a cake*. Strict grammarians don't usually like that (*yet!* :), though.